# Is it possible for a shader to process a composed scene (resulting from more than one texture)?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using a fragment shader in OpenGL to do (among other things) gamma correction with the aim of linearizing the relationship between my input texture data and what I end up seeing on the screen.  But according to my current understanding, this is incompatible with alpha-blending:   two semi-transparent textures can be blended linearly together, but as far as I understand it this can only happen *after* the fragment shaders have done their thing, and hence *after* gamma-correction in my case. And that breaks the linearity of the whole system.

To illustrate, let's suppose we have two textures overlapping at a certain pixel location: texture 1 is closer to the camera with colour `vec4( c1, alpha )` and texture 2 is behind it with opaque colour `c2`.  The same shader runs on both textures and applies the inverse of the screen's gamma function to each, so what I believe gets rendered is:

```
alpha * inverse_gamma(c1) +  (1-alpha) * inverse_gamma(c2)
```

whereas what I really want is:

```
inverse_gamma(    alpha * c1  + (1 - alpha) * c2   )
```

I guess what I had hoped would exist is some kind of "scene shader" that runs *after* the whole frame buffer has been composed, to which I could move my implementation of `inverse_gamma()`.  But I haven't found any reference to concepts like this.  Is there a way to do this?

(I'm separately targeting OpenGL 2.1/GLSL 1.2  as well as OpenGL 3.3+/GLSL 3.3+ so I realize that there might be two different answers for the two settings.)

Comment: "*whereas what I really want is:*" Why do you really want that? What colorspace are your textures in? Is your FS linearizing them, or are they linear in the texture (which, quite frankly, is rather unlikely).

Comment: @NicolBolas I definitely want that. It’s for vision science, where c1 and c2 are specified by sets of equations and you need to be confident that those equations are reproduced faithfully and linearly in the luminance of the screen.

Comment: You could render your entire scene to a framebuffer. A framebuffer can be subsequently used as a texture. So you can redraw the entire scene (not individual fragments, but the complete image) through a second shader which implements gamma correction.

Comment: @HansLehnert  thanks, it looks like that's the answer.  I hadn't heard about deferred rendering but it looks like it's quite a common approach in general.  Should work in my OpenGL3+ contexts but not in my legacy contexts, it seems...

Comment: I think this can be achieved using pre- multiplied alpha textures also. Might be better way to handle transparent objects than deferred rendering.

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni  it would presumably allow better performance if things could be pre-calculated.  But as far as I've understood it (and I haven't, very well, so please correct me) premultiplied alpha would allow me to do `inverse_gamma(c1*alpha) + (1-alpha) * inverse_gamma(c2)` i.e. still a linear combination of two non-linear functions and not the same as I'm trying to achieve.  Is that correct?